# Import modules in jupyterlab project

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-module

I use Jupyter Lab via pipenv installation. So I have to run it inside a pipenv virtual environment.

I have a directory `dir` with two subdictories `my_modules` and `notebooks`. Inside `notebooks` I organize my ipynb's. Inside `my_modules` I put some `.py` code I usually use in the notebooks.

It seems that the default working directory of a notebook is the directory where it is located. I was wondering... is there's a way to set the default working directory of the notebooks (of this particular installation of Jupyter Lab) to be the `dir` directory?

If not, is there a way that I could relative import the modules from `my_modules` from ipynb's inside `notebooks` without resorting to cell code such as `%cd ..` or `import sys; sys.path.append('some/dir')` at the start of each notebook

Answer (score 1):

You can change the working directory of a notebook during runtime by using `os.chdir('/some/directory/')`.

To relatively import modules without `sys.path.append()`, you can set an environment variable `PYTHONPATH` which contains the directory of your modules (you might need to restart Jupyter Lab for this to take effect). On Windows, you can set an environment variable by Start -> type "Edit environment variables for your account".